# Mac connects to server through dyndns loop back instead through local network

Tags: macos, networking, mac, vnc, dynamic-dns

in our office, we have several people working with macs. A mac mini with several external external hdd's provides storage and backup capabilities for our collaborative work.

Recently, we hired an it service to modify our setup to allow for remote access to work data. I don't know the specifics, but it's based on vnc and dyndns.

It is working as expected now, but we have one annoying problem: the service employee demonstrated how to connect via the remote route using one of our office iMacs. And now this iMac will *always* connect this way instead of connecting to the server through the local network. At least, this is what we suspect - the connection is slower than before and if the internet connection is lost, the server will disconnect as well, while all other macs keep their connection. We can't tell for sure, since the remote connection "looks" just like the local connection in Finder once it has been established.

Disconnecting and reconnecting the mac in question to the server appears to be helping sometimes, but only until the next reboot.

So, basically, my questions are:

- How can I tell whether the mac is connected through the local network or the remote route?
- How can I make sure that the iMac won't use the remote route anymore?
- Are there other possible reasons for the unreliable connection we are experiencing with this single iMac?

Thanks alot!!